# Kafka internal storage

Tags: apache-kafka

As per, Kafka book

> Producer publishes messages to topic. These messages will be written
>   in a segment and after that batch of message will be stored to disk.
>
> Consumer subscribes to a topic and read the message form the segment.

I read that physically segment is nothing but files. I am confused what is the role of disk if we are storing message in segments(file system) .

Can someone explain me the relationship between segments and disk ?

Comment: Yes, segments are kafka data files. But where will files will be stored, on disk only rt?

Comment: I am asking not sure ..

Answer (score 0):

Messages are published into Topic/Partition. When a broker receives messages, it will write them into the OS page-cache (i.e : the unused portions of the main memory). OS will then periodically flush (fsync) dirty pages on disk.

Kafka physically organises data on file system into directories named with KAFKA_LOGS_DIR/- which are store into the logs directories configured on each broker (default : tmp/kafka-logs/)

Each of this directories contains a number of log-structured file call segment in which messages are written sequentially. In addition, each segment log is attached to two index files/.